Total radiation and intensity definition
We define radiation intensity per area and per solid angle.
Consider the Sun example.
When integration over solid angle we obtain total radiation in all directions.
When integration over area we obtain total radiation over all sphere surface.
But isn't that double counting?
What is the area element that we integrate intensity over?

Each point on the Sun’s surface radiates into space in various directions. So doing a double integral is not double counting.

Each element of the area of a surface radiates into all solid angles, therefore a double integral of the specific intensity over solid angle and area is involved (and a triple integral if you want this over all frequencies) and could be done in either order.
Conventionally when considering radiation from a surface we consider each point on the surface and integrate $I(\theta, \phi) \cos\theta$ over all solid angle, or just the outward hemisphere if we want the outwardly directed flux per unit area:
$$\frac{dF}{dA} = \int\limits_{\rm hemisphere} I(\theta,\phi)\cos\theta\, d\Omega = \int^{2\pi}_{\phi=0} \int^{\pi/2}_{\theta=0} I(\theta,\phi)\cos\theta\, \sin\theta\ d\theta\, d\phi  $$
giving $\pi I$ for isotropic radiation. This is then the flux per unit area from the surface and needs to be integrated over the surface area (or multiplied by the surface area for a uniformly bright surface) to work out the total luminosity.

It can be double counting, if you don't do it right, and it's easy to do wrong.
For the Sun (treated as a spherical blackbody at $T_{\odot}=5778\,$K), Planck tells us the spectral radiance is:
$$
B(\nu, T) =
\frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}
\frac 1
{e^{\frac{hv}{kT}-1}}
$$
which is power (energy per time) per area per steradian per frequency.
To get the total power emitted from an area you have to integrate over $2\pi$ solid angle, and
over frequency of the radiation. You get radiant existence described by Stefan-Boltzmann Law:
$$M = \sigma T^4 $$
From that, you get the solar luminosity by integrating over the Sun's surface:
$$L_{\odot} = 4\pi R_{\oplus}^2 M \approx 3.8\times 10^{26}\,{\rm W}$$
(with an efficacy of 98 W/lm, so surprise, it's tuned to human vision).
Now from here, to get the solar power impinging on Earth, you compute the fraction of total solid angle subtended by Earth (radius $r_{\oplus}$) at semi-major axis $R_{\oplus}$, and multiply by the Luminosity:
$$ P = \frac{\pi r_{\oplus}^2}{4\pi R_{\oplus}^2} L_{\odot} \approx 173\,{\rm PW}$$
The other option to follow the figure (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radianc):

and integrate over for each point on the Earth's surface (facing the sun) and integral over the surface of the sun that includes the normals to the surface elements and the differential elements of the solid angle...and that is messy.
